# Save LaTeX/AucTeX generated auxiliary files to a separate directory EXCEPT for the PDF file

Tags: latex, init-file, auctex, pdf, tex

I am using AucTex in Emacs to compile my LaTeX files. Is there a way to keep just the PDF file in the current directory and send all the other auxiliary files to a separate folder? I have set `TeX-output-dir` to `./tmp`. However, this saves the pdf file to the `tmp` folder as well. I would like to have the pdf file in the current directory. Thanks a lot for your time! :)